# Post to facebook page via php api where "Disable posts by other people on the Page" is enabled

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

We've created a facebook app that autoposts articles to the page associated by its admin to our app.

We have setelled the right permissions ***'manage_pages', 'publish_pages'***, and the pages are loaded but we found out that ***"can_post"*** value returned with each page is set to ***"false"***, when the user listing the pages is the admin. After some digging we found out that it's because of **"Disable posts by other people on the Page"** option that was enabled.

So the question is: **is there a way to post to those pages when this option is enabled, cause the admin doesn't want to allow visistors to post on his page ?**

**Edit:**

As it could seems unclear for some people, I'm adding more informations about the process, that I thought it's obvious:

1. So beside the right permissions
2. We're asking for long-live user access token
3. Then use it to get a permanent page access token, so **we can post as a "Page"**

But the problem occurs before we get to this stage as from the beginning, when the user accepts the permissions, and when we list his pages, those pages are listed like "cannot post on it", where others says that it's allowed to post on it. And due to this difference we found out that it was caused by the option I talked about above: *"Disable posts by other people on the Page"*

Regards

Comment: It’s not done by asking for permissions alone … you need to use the right kind of access token, too, which by your description you did not. You need to use a page access token, if you want to post as the page. You must have used a user access token for the page admin, which still means they would post as a user, and _that_ is what your page settings are forbidding.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for the comment (and maybe for the down vote too :) ). Anyway I edited the question so it can be more clear. If you could give any advice on the matter that could be helpful, I thank you in advance.

Comment: _“those pages are listed like "cannot post on it", where others says that it's allowed to post on it.”_ – that’s because you are using the admin’s _user_ token to request the list of their pages - and as a user, they are not allowed to post by page settings. Now go and request `{page-id}?fields=can_post` with a _page_ access token for the page ... et voilà, now that says it can post, _because_ using the page token the app is allowed to post _as_ the page.

Comment: Thanks man what you said was correct, and it says that it can post now. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We have setelled the right permissions 'manage_pages', 'publish_pages', and the pages are loaded but we found out that "can_post" value returned with each page is set to "false", when the user listing the pages is the admin. After some digging we found out that it's because of "Disable posts by other people on the Page" option that was enabled.

That’s because you are using the admin’s user token to request the list of their pages - and as a user, they are not allowed to post by page settings.

Go and request `{page-id}?fields=can_post` with a page access token for the page ... et voilà, now that says it can post, because using the page token the app is allowed to post *as* the page.